# Python - loop over intersection between shapefiles

Tags: python, intersection, arcpy

I need to write a loop (in arcpy) for 10 climate files with respect to 1 census area file. Thus, I need 10 intersections. I have problems with the syntax when it comes to naming the output files: I get ERROR 00800.

I know this is related to concatenation, and might be easy for many of you. It's been a while since I coded in Python. Find my code below, I appreciate your help

```
output2 = ""
shapes_input =["RCP4_2040_1", "RCP4_2040_2"]                      
for shapes in shapes_input:
output = shapes + "_AU"
output2 = '"' + output + '"'
arcpy.Intersect_analysis(shapes, "AKLmbAU2013", output2)
```

Comment: This error has been reported at least 20 times at the [gis.se] Stack Exchange: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error-000800  For ArcPy questions I think you should research/ask there first.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to get for the value of `output2` is:

```
RCP4_2040_1_AU
```

What you are getting by including the quotation marks:

```
"RCP4_2040_1_AU"
```

So instead of the expected syntax `arcpy.Intersect_analysis(shapes, 'AKLmbAU2013', 'RCP4_2040_1_AU')` you're passing `arcpy.Intersect_analysis(shapes, 'AKLmbAU2013', '"RCP4_2040_1_AU"')` -- i.e., your variable value includes quotation marks. Just leave those off and you should be fine.